# Flatten list column in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a column in a dataframe which I split into three separate columns using colsplit.

```
df <- transform(df, concatenation = colsplit(concatenation, pattern="->-",
 names = c('att1', 'att2','att3', 'att4')))
```

OR

```
df$concatenation  <- colsplit(concatenation, pattern="->-",
 names = c('att1', 'att2','att3', 'att4')))

concatenation 
a->-a->-b->-c
b->-a->-b->-d
3->-a->-x->-c
2->-a->-y->-8
```

Now I have the following columns, concatenation.att1, concatenation.att2, etc.

```
concatenation.att1 concatenation.att2 concatenation.att3 concatenation.att4
a                  a                  b                  c
b                  a                  b                  d
3                  a                  x                  c
2                  a                  y                  8
```

When trying to export this dataframe to CSV I get the following error:

```
Error in ncol(xj) : object 'xj' not found
```

OR

```
Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame") && ncol(xj) > 1L) X[[j]] <- as.matrix(X[[j]]) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

From research I have deduced that this is from my nested column, however I cant find a simple way to flatten the dataframe (as below) to export to csv.

```
att1 att2 att3 att4
a    a    b    c
b    a    b    d
3    a    x    c
2    a    y    8
```

Currently I am reassigning the data to the appropriate level and deleting the stacked column, but I am sure there is a better way to do this.

```
df$att1 <- df$concatenation$att1
df$att2 <- df$concatenation$att2
df$att3 <- df$concatenation$att3
df$att4 <- df$concatenation$att4

df$concatenation <- NULL
```

Below is a reproducible example:

```
#read in table
df <- read.table(textConnection(
  "concatenation     Value
AFG->-Afghanistan->-1950->-True    20,249
  AFG->-Afghanistan->-1951->-True    21,352
  AFG->-Afghanistan->-1952->-True    22,532
  AFG->-Afghanistan->-1953->-True    23,557
  AFG->-Afghanistan->-1954->-True    24,555
  ALB->-Albania->-1950->-True    8,097
  ALB->-Albania->-1951->-True    8,986"), header=TRUE)

#Split concatenation var
df <- transform(df, concatenation = colsplit(concatenation, pattern="->-",
                                             names = c('att1', 'att2','att3', 'att4')))
#write to csv
write.csv(df, "myfile.csv")
```

Comment: *I have a column in a dataframe which I split into three separate columns using colsplit*...it would be nice to see the column values. *I cant find a simple way to flatten the dataframe*...it would be nice see the desired output.

Comment: I haved added in the tables with the intended output. Hopefully that makes it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `tidyr::separate` will do it.

```
nm <- c('att1', 'att2','att3', 'att4')
df2 <- tidyr::separate(df, concatenation, nm, sep = "->-")

sapply(df2, typeof)
#        att1        att2        att3        att4       Value 
# "character" "character" "character" "character"   "integer" 
write.csv(df2)
# "","att1","att2","att3","att4","Value"
# "1","AFG","Afghanistan","1950","True","20,249"
# "2","AFG","Afghanistan","1951","True","21,352"
# "3","AFG","Afghanistan","1952","True","22,532"
# "4","AFG","Afghanistan","1953","True","23,557"
# "5","AFG","Afghanistan","1954","True","24,555"
# "6","ALB","Albania","1950","True","8,097"
# "7","ALB","Albania","1951","True","8,986"
```

And in base R, `strsplit()` will work.

```
df3 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(as.character(df$concatenation), "->-"))
cbind(setNames(df3, nm), df["Value"])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to transform here? Try this:

```
df$concatenation <- colsplit(df$concatenation, "->-",
                    names = c("att1", "att2","att3", "att4"))
```

Comment: True, I just ran it without the transform and it did produce the same results. However, it is still leading to errors when writing to CSV.   --   Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame") && ncol(xj) > 1L) X[[j]] <- as.matrix(X[[j]]) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed